# Código para Htaccess para redirigir index.html y www a non-www?

Tags: .htaccess, redirección, mod-rewrite

Quisiera saber si index.html cuenta como contenido duplicado

Cómo puedo redireccionarlo junto con mi url con www a mi dirección **ejemplo** http://ejemplo.com.

Answer (score 3):

Para redirigir de www a no-www:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Para redirigir index.html a /:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```